# JavaScript to take data from Google Sheets and populate a Google Site template website page

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sites

I was hoping someone could help me write a code or point me to where I could find something to help me do this:

**Take Google Sheet data and populate a Google Site template page with it.**

This would save me a lot of time because I have all these pages that I want to populate this data with and I have created the template for the look of the page itself.  However, I have no idea how to do this.  I was thinking about trying to use an add-on to put the data into a template Google doc (I think I found something like that) and then put the Google doc on the webpage, but I would much prefer it right on the web page.

I know this is a lot and I would appreciate any help.  If you know of a code that would do this for me (and somewhere that would best help me understand it) as well as any add-ons they have in Google Sheets or Google Sites that may do this (I have not been able to find one), please let me know.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free coding site (unfortunately, I have a stack of work for someone to do). Perhaps you could find a developer who could spend some time with you remotely to teach you how to do this?

Comment: Thanks for responding halfer.  I was just posting to see what was out there in case I missed something.  I hoped to get a developer on this for a while, but our project may not have the funds.  But, again, thank you.